# Ubuntu 12.10 issue: only wallpaper and curser appear, no menu or icons etc

Tags: 12.10

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unity doesn’t load, no Launcher, no Dash appears](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears)

I have installed Ubuntu 12.10 on an old Compaq N800v. It all seems fine, I get to log in ok, and then all I get is the wallpaper and the curser. I have tried resetting unity, by installing the right bits to allow the command 'unity-reset' to function, but it errors horribly when I run it. any easy fix?
thanks

Comment: OP clearly says he reset Unity already.

Comment: What errors do you get when you run `unity --reset`? (Please edit your question to provide this information.)

Answer (score 2):

If you have a stock n800v your hardware may be too far under the minimum requirement for Unity:

From : https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DesktopExperienceTeam/UnityHardwareRequirements

Minimum
1.66 GHz               CPU*
32 bits                ARCH
1GB                    RAM
4 GB                   HD
intel GMA 950          GPU**
1.4                    OpenGL
1.4                    GLX
1024x600               Display
Dell Mini 9            Reference

Considering this, in your position, I would simply use a lighter interface for Ubuntu like LXDE. You can either clean install it from http://lubuntu.net/ or download the "lubuntu" packages from synaptic or apt-get.

Answer (score 0):

Erase your hard drive and put Ubuntu 12.04 on it instead. It comes with Unity 2D by default, which is made for lower end hardware. 12.04 is also much more stable and is supported for at least 5 years.